# Grunt.js Get JavaScript Filesize and Show On Page

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

Is there a way using Grunt.js uglify plugin to print/show/display the file size of my javascript files back to my HTML page after it's been concatenating and/or minified?

What's the recommended plugins? I'm already using [grunt-env](https://github.com/jsoverson/grunt-env) and [grunt-preprocess](https://github.com/jsoverson/grunt-preprocess) to display grunt variables on my HTML page. I also use concat and uglify.

If anyone can point me in the right direction I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

The [report](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify#report) option provides some before-and-after info.

Using it with the `min` option, I get something like this:

```
Running "uglify:generated" (uglify) task
File "dist\public\afile.js" created.
Original: 1101711 bytes.
Minified: 233615 bytes.
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't use the correct terminology. I don't mean print as in "show" the output in my CL tool, rather get the variable from say uglify plugin. I need to get the original and minified filesize. Capture that variable and display it on my HTML page.

Comment: Reporting calls [minMaxInfo](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify/blob/master/tasks/uglify.js#L146) which is exported in [grunt-lib-contrib](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify/blob/master/tasks/uglify.js#L146) and *that* uses `grunt.log.writeln`.  So, no.  Not out of the box.